# Access file from chrome node docker

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker

I am using selenium grid docker to run my automation testsuites.

I hv configured chrome node docker to run my testcases on the browser.

In my testcases I am downloading some file from the web. It is getting downloaded in "/home/seluser/Downloads/". I need the content of the file as the content is dynamic. How I can access file downloaded on the docker image from machine where my automation is running.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to mount the `/home/seluser/Downloads` path somewhere on your host machine. Change your docker run command to add something like `-v /path/on/host:/home/seluser/Downloads` and all of the saved files will be accessible on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  docker cp command

```
docker cp <name of the container>:/home/seluser/Downloads copied_files
```

where copied_files is a directory where files will be copied